# CoreAudio: Creating kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2 presets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audiounit

I have a basic workflow for an **iOS app** in which `.aupreset` files are created for various **AudioUnits** such as **AUSampler, delay, etc..** and are then loaded in my **iOS app**.

I need a reverb effect and see that the available reverb for desktop (which `AULab` can use) is `kAudioUnitSubType_MatrixReverb`, however the reverb that **iOS** can use is `kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2`.

Hence I have no way of designing `kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2` preset files.

Any ideas on how I could load these to `AULab` or create them?